# How to create singleton object, which could be used both as type and value (similar to None)?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'd like to have custom NotSet value which could be used in type hinting similar to None.

```py
NotSet = ?


class Client:
    def partial_update(
            self,
            obj_id: int,
            obj_field: int | None | NotSet = NotSet,
            ...
    ):
        # Do not update fields which were not specified explicitly.
        if obj_field is NotSet:
           # do not update obj_field
        else: 
           # update obj_field
        ...
```

**Not good enough solutions:**

1. Use `None`.

- None itself is reserved for business logic. Fields can be nullable.

2. Use built-in `ellipsis`:

```
from types import EllipsisType


def partial_update(
   obj_field: int | None | EllipsisType = ...,
):
   pass
```

- Using built-in Ellipsis is not explicit enough
- You cannot use ellipsis as type either: `obj_field: int | None | ... = ...,`

3. Use custom singleton.

```
class NotSetType:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


NotSet = NotSetType()


def partial_update(
   obj_field: int | None | NotSetType = NotSet,
):
   pass
```

- The best one, but still NotSetType is used instead of desired NotSet for type hinting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that, class can not be an instance of itself (unless it's `type`, but that's a different story).

(Actually, it can:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        return x(name, bases, dct)

class NotSet(type, metaclass=Meta):
    pass


def partial_update(
   obj_field: int | None | NotSet = NotSet,
):
    if obj_field is NotSet:
        print('not updating')
    else:
        print(f'updating to {obj_field}')
```

```
>>> NotSet
<class '__main__.NotSet'>
>>> type(NotSet)
<class '__main__.NotSet'>

>>> partial_update()
not updating
>>> partial_update(None)
updating to None
>>> partial_update(4)
updating to 4
```

but your static type checker might not be happy, e.x. mypy isn't.)

I think your third option is the most pythonic, explicit, and understandable. Another suggestion for you is to use `**kwargs` instead of the function arguments:

```
def partial_update(
    **kwargs,
):
    for field, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(obj, field, value)
```

Although you lose type hints and field names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by taking advantage of [`typing.Protocol`s, which define a structural type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/). Type-checkers should only check member existence and type conformance.

You just need to make a structural type which looks the same regardless of whether it's an instance or class, but put members on it which (probably) won't match any other kind of class. Something like the following:

```py
import typing as t

@t.runtime_checkable
class NotSet(t.Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def __not_set() -> None: ...
```

Live demonstration ([mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=8a5693ea6d89e6135dbad631543e1dce), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.337&code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYA7A5nAhgZwQKHwAEYA6KAV1RlAFMB9AYwAtbGBrLAIwBtb9GPXHgByEGAGVaMABRkAClHERGEHgEoAXPji64RHDCw1GIacwgATHXsu0AZnHr1U4%2Bjmkz1cALQA%2BODFUWk04UnDCLFCxSWk4AF5A8SkYfCwEpOC0jKQwfnTEiC4AKzZUgrgARmzEmJTCLlCyADE0LB4AbTrpAF0M7tTGJtJW1Hb%2B5OkauC5pxnwgA)):

```
>>> a: NotSet = NotSet  # OK
>>> a = None            # Error
>>> a = type            # Error
>>> a = object          # Error
>>> a = 1               # Error
>>> a = NotSet          # OK (reassignment)
>>>
>>> b: t.Final[NotSet] = NotSet  # OK
>>> c: t.Final = NotSet          # OK
>>> a = b                        # OK
>>> a = c                        # OK
```

[Type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html) with `is` won't be recognised like `None`, as type-checkers probably special case `None`. You can use `isinstance` if you need this:

```py
def f(val: int | NotSet = NotSet) -> None:
    if isinstance(val, NotSet):
        raise RuntimeError
    else:
        print(val + 7)  # OK
```

Comment: Your idea is inspiring! I think we can define a `TypeGuard` here to better satisfy static type checkers: `def isNotSet(x: t.Any) -> t.TypeGuard[NotSet]: return x is NotSet`.